# Can warning be shown twice when excel workbook is closed?

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a code which gives warning when the workbook is closed. By default excel warns only once (that too if current changes are not saved). I want warning to come twice. First time it should ask are you sure? when the person hits yes, again system should ask are you sure.

So far my code is as follows, but it is not working properly. With the below code, warning is only displayed once. Please can someone help?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 Dim mbResult As Integer
Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook

mbResult = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit this program?", _
 vbYesNo)

    Select Case mbResult
    Case vbYesNo
        MsgBox "You are about to exit this program, are you sure?"
        Case vbYes
Cancel = True

        Case vbNo
          ' Do nothing and allow the macro to run

    Exit Sub

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: MsgBox returns vbYes if Yes button is clicked, not vbYesNo.
Change:

    Select Case mbResult
        Case vbYesNo

to

    Select Case mbResult
        Case vbYes

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Workbook_BeforeClose` event to prompt the user to check if they really want to do something.

Both these two codes below ask the user twice for confirmation if they want to close the workbook. The first one use the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event, so you will need to do something in the code to save changes etc.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to close the workbook?", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbYes Then
        If MsgBox("Are you relly sure you want to close the workbook?", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbYes Then
           Call MsgBox("No turning back now", vbOKOnly, "User Anwser")
        End If
    Else
        Call MsgBox("That was close", vbOKOnly, "User Anwser")
    End If
End Sub
```

This second set of code goes in a normal module and you could call it from your macro when you want the user to close the workbook. I have put in a workbook save so that changes are not lost.

```
Sub Close()
  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to close the workbook?", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbYes Then
        If MsgBox("Are you relly sure you want to close the workbook?", vbYesNo, "User Input") = vbYes Then
           Call MsgBox("No turning back now", vbOKOnly, "User Anwser")
           ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        End If
    Else
        Call MsgBox("That was close", vbOKOnly, "User Anwser")
    End If
End Sub
```

How it looks running,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can directly handle the return value of a `MsgBox` like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit this file?", vbYesNo)
        Case vbYes
            Cancel = MsgBox("You are about to exit this program, are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo
        Case vbNo
            Cancel = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

or, which is equivalent:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit this file?", vbYesNo) = vbNo
    If Not Cancel Then Cancel = MsgBox("You are about to exit this program, are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo
End Sub
```